# In JSF , how to list in editable datatable without initialing in init block or in constructor

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

In my application I am using primefaces editable datatable, those List(cmFieldsList) values need to be rendered dynamically based on request parameters(blkcode).

If I initialize the list in constructor I can edit and save the datatable objects.
For my application each time dynamic list is needed based on request parameters, so without initializing in constructor I could not edit or save the data in my datatable.
If i try to edit the same without initializing I am getting Exception like below

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: row is unavailable
>       at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.getRowData(ListDataModel.java:69)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowData(UIData.java:433)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.queueEvent(DataTable.java:522)
>       at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:42)
>       at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:64)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:329)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:57)

So Without initializing in constructor how Could I achieve this.

My JSF Managed Bean code is

```
package com.dynamic.mbeans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import com.dynamic.model.CmFields;
import com.dynamic.services.CmFieldService;

@ManagedBean(name="cmFieldListBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CmFieldController implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6250736369064467010L;

private CmFields cmFields;
private List<CmFields> cmFieldsList;
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.blkCode}")
public String blkCode;

public CmFieldController(){
    cmFields= new CmFields();
    //cmFieldsList= new ArrayList<CmFields>();
    //cmFieldsList.add(cmFields); 
}

@ManagedProperty("#{cmFieldService}")
private CmFieldService cmFieldService;

public String showForms(){
    System.out.println("blkCode =="+blkCode);
    cmFieldsList = cmFieldService.listAllCmField(blkCode);//lists CmFields from DB
    return "dynamic-cmfields-form";
}

public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    System.out.println("event started");
    System.out.println("event ended");
   // FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("CmFields Edited", ((CmFields) event.getObject()).getBlkCode() );  

   //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}  

public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("CmFields Cancelled", ((CmFields) event.getObject()).getBlkCode());  

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}  

public CmFields getCmFields() {
    return cmFields;
}

public void setCmFields(CmFields cmFields) {
    this.cmFields = cmFields;
}

public CmFieldService getCmFieldService() {
    return cmFieldService;
}

public void setCmFieldService(CmFieldService cmFieldService) {
    this.cmFieldService = cmFieldService;
}

public List<CmFields> getCmFieldsList() {
    return cmFieldsList;
}

public void setCmFieldsList(List<CmFields> cmFieldsList) {
    this.cmFieldsList = cmFieldsList;
}

public String getBlkCode() {
    return blkCode;
}

public void setBlkCode(String blkCode) {
    this.blkCode = blkCode;
}


}
```

My JSF code for sending request parameters to Managed bean is

```
 <h:form>
<h:commandLink action="#{cmFieldListBean.showForms}" value="LIST SALESMAN" >
<f:param name="blkCode" value="SALESMAN" />
 </h:commandLink>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <h:commandLink action="#{cmFieldListBean.showForms}" value="LIST SALESMAN COMPANY" >
 <f:param name="blkCode" value="SALESMAN_COMP" />
 </h:commandLink>


 </h:form>
```

My JSF code for listing in datatable  is

```
<h:form id="form">  

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

<p:dataTable var="cmList" value="#{cmFieldListBean.cmFieldsList}" id="cmFieldsList" editable="true" preserveDataModel="false">  

    <f:facet name="header">  
       Grid Editing
    </f:facet>  

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{cmFieldListBean.onEdit}" update=":form:cmFieldsList" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{cmFieldListBean.onCancel}" update=":form:cmFieldsList" />  

    <p:column headerText="Caption" style="width:200px">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{cmList.fieldCaption}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{cmList.fieldCaption}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Field Name" style="width:150px">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{cmList.fieldName}" /> 
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{cmList.fieldName}" style="width:100%"/>    
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Data Type" style="width:150px">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{cmList.dataType}" /> 
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{cmList.dataType}" style="width:100%"/>    
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>  


    <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">  
        <p:rowEditor />  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: You are already initializing the `cmFieldList` within `showForms()` - where is the problem? Can you rephrase your question? Do the different `blkCode` need different types Lists?

Answer (score 0):

change your bean scope to `@ViewScoped` :The view scope will be used in a lot of cases for the backing of a data table as you don't need to read the data in the database every time you change the sorting or filtering. This of course if the list of records you want to show isn't too long and read them all at once in memory.